# NSCalender returns wrong year

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

I get year 2012 from dateFromComponents and my current date is 2013. Why is that? I haven't change the year anywhere.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[comp year]); //2013

NSLog(@"%@", [cal dateFromComponents:comp]); // 2012-12-31 23:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: TimeZone/NSLocale issue, I guess?

Comment: Have you checked your system time, check on a device and see same happens

Comment: @SteveJobs I did check from the device. It's like this on every device i tested with.

Comment: You always get "2012-12-31 23:00:00 +0000"??  You'd have to be awfully lucky to always get that date/time.  Looks to me like you're not showing us all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion takes the time zone from the calendar into account, which you probably don't want in this case when just splitting a date into components. Set the time zone to GMT and it should give you the result you want;

```
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

Comment: If I set timezone I get 2013-01-01 00:00:00 +0000. Its the right year, but wrong month and day

Comment: @Toydor Yes, that is exactly new year 2013, which has the correct year 2013. Since you're using `components:NSCalendarUnitYear`, the year is all you get. What would be your expected result?